# Sony SmartWatch2: want to change advanced vibration patterns

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch, vibration

This is a part of examples, HelloEvents, on Sony addon sdk' examples.

I've managed to access the startVibrator and change vibrations successfully on SmartWatch2.

But, I want to change the vibration pattern more details such as pattern like android vibrate, eg.{500,500,500,500,1000,1000,1000,1000}.

So, I used startVibrator twice, but it didn't work. It just did last one(`startVibrate(1000,1000,2`)).

for example,

```
 if (event.getAction() == Control.Intents.TOUCH_ACTION_RELEASE) {`enter code here`
            if (mTouchRect.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                sendEventToActivity(EventType.TOUCH, event.getX() + ", " + event.getY());

                startVibrator(500, 500, 2); // not working 
                startVibrator(1000,1000,2); // only working 
                }        
             }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you need to startVibrator after the first one is finished. And most likely you also need to exit the event handler. So either there is a vibe-end event or you need to schedule a timed one.

Comment: Post the code for start vibrator. I know that came with example, but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

The second vibration pattern is overriding the first one. You need to send it, after the first pattern is complete. You can do that for example by using `postDelayed`, where the delay will be the total duration of your first pattern.